# Validate range of date at ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, visual-studio, devexpress

So at the moment I'm developing an application that requires to save a value with a starting date and an ending date. One of the restrictions it's that If I insert a new register, I have to validate that there's no registers that contains any of the months defined by the new value ( I know that I didn't explained myself properly here, but English is not my native language) Let me give a visual example.

So let's that that there's a table which contains these values:

```
ID      |Start Date   | Ending date
001      05/08/2014      05/12/2014
002      03/05/2014      03/04/2014
```

So the validation has to make sure that If i try to ad a new value like these:

`003| 05/09/2014  |05/11/2014` it won't allow me to make the save the Data, because there's already a range which contains the same months that I wan't to add.

I know how to make the c # part. However I'm struggling with the SQL, since is not my best area. Any help or guidance will be appreciated. Currently working with Oracle 9-11.

Answer (score 0):

asuming you table name is : **Your_table_name_here**, you can try this script.

```
Create Table Your_table_name_here
(
    Id Varchar2(25) Not Null,
    Start_date Date Not Null,
    Ending_date Date Not Null,
    Constraint Your_table_name_here_pk Primary Key(Id)
)
/

-- create a database trigger to automatically validate the date entered --

Create Or Replace Trigger Tbi_your_table_name_here
   Before Insert
   On Your_table_name_here
   Referencing New As New Old As Old
   For Each Row
Declare
   Tmpvar                        Number;
Begin
   Tmpvar := 0;

   Begin
      Select 1
        Into Tmpvar
        From Your_table_name_here
       Where (:new.Start_date Between Start_date And Ending_date
           Or  :new.Ending_date Between Start_date And Ending_date)
         And Rownum < 2;

      Raise_application_error( -20996, 'Date Range, already in database');
   Exception
      When No_data_found Then
         Null; -- is OK, no dates found in range
      When Others Then
         Raise_application_error( -20997, 'Incorrect Date : ' || Sqlerrm);
   End;
Exception
   When Others Then
      -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
      Raise;
End Tbi_your_table_name_here;
/

Show Errors
/
```

basically, you create a trigger that validates data entered to the table.

hope this helps